# Make a foreach array from mysql SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM da_questions");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

which selects everything from the table `da_questions`. Now this is in a file called `config.php` which file is required in all my pages of my website. Now I want to do the following on my external pages... let's say index.php

```
<?php foreach($results as $question): ?>

   <p><?php echo $question['question_title']; ?></p>
   <br />
   <p><?php echo $question['question_text']; ?></p>
   <br />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My file outlay is like shown below:

```
index.php

config/
  config.php
```

How can I do this?

Comment: not sure I understand. why not just `$results = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reult))
{
$results[] = $row;
}`

Comment: @FrankConry Or even easier `$results = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: @FrankConry post in answer? So I can abide by stackoverflow policies...

Comment: how did you you make `$results` on index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM da_questions");
   $results = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $results[] = $row;
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
```

in the index.php write as below

```
  include('config/config.php');

 <?php foreach($results as $question): ?>

    <p><?php echo $question['question_title']; ?></p>
    <br />
    <p><?php echo $question['question_text']; ?></p>
   <br />

   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
$results = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reult)) { $results[] = $row; }
```

or as @Phil pointed out:

```
$results = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```